# IdentityServer3 - Client and Secret

Tags: jwt, identityserver3

I am going through some tutorials to see if I can use IdentityServer3 issue/handle tokens to be used in authorizing access to some Web Api endpoints.

One of the concepts I am not quite understanding is the `Client` and `Secret`. When using OAuth in previous projects I never had to pass along a `client` or `secret` value in the header. I only passed the `grant_type`, `username`, and `password`. Yet IdentityServer seems to expect a `client` and a `secret` along with `grant_type`, `username`, and `password`.

Why is a `client` necessary? Shouldn't the IdentityServer just pass back a bearer token regardless of the type of client? Also, what is the purpose of the `secret` parameter? Is this used to create the signature of the JWT token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`client_id` and `client_secret` are a [part of the OAuth spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2), not implementation specific to Identity Server. They are part of the client registration, which I like to think of as an access control list, checking to see if the requesting party is authorized to receive access tokens using the requested flow and scopes.

Unregistered clients are [supported in the OAuth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.4) spec but I've yet to encounter one.

From the sounds of it you have been using the ResourceOwner flow which requires a `grant_type` of `password`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, multiple `scope`'s, `username` and `password`.

`client_id` and `client_secret` can also be base64 encoded and passed sent in the `Authorization` header using the `Basic` scheme.

The secret is not used for JWT validation, it is only used to verify the incoming client.

Comment: Thank you Scott! I have been reading your tutorials. The are very well laid out. I am having trouble trying to figure out how to use IdentityServer3 to get back a bearer token so I can then protect my API with claim attributes.